# XPath to select multiple elements at once?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm currently doing this to build an array called `$tables`, but wondering if there is an easier way to do this?

```
$tables = array();
$abbr = $states_xml->xpath('//StateAbbr');
$names = $states_xml->xpath('//StateName');

// State Abbreviations...
while(list($key,$table) = each($abbr)) {
    $tables[$key]['Abbr'] = (string) trim($table);
}

// State Names...
while(list($key,$name) = each($names)) {
    $tables[$key]['Name'] = (string) trim($name);
}
```

Is it possible to call `StateAbbr` and `StateName` elements in 1 go and have them be outputted in an array in the same format as `$tables` is?

So, tables array will look something like this:

```
array(57) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Abbr"]=>
    string(2) "AL"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(7) "Alabama"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Abbr"]=>
    string(2) "AK"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(6) "Alaska"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Abbr"]=>
    string(2) "AS"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(14) "American Samoa"
  }
... and so on...
```

Basically, the `$states_xml` looks like this:

```
<diffgr:diffgram
    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet
        xmlns="">
        <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
            <StateAbbr>AL </StateAbbr>
            <StateName>Alabama</StateName>
        </Table>
        <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
            <StateAbbr>AK </StateAbbr>
            <StateName>Alaska</StateName>
        </Table>
        <Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
            <StateAbbr>AS </StateAbbr>
            <StateName>American Samoa</StateName>
        </Table>
        <Table diffgr:id="Table4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
            <StateAbbr>AP </StateAbbr>
            <StateName>AP</StateName>
        </Table>
        ...
    </NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

I am using `$states_xml = simplexml_load_string(THE STRING ABOVE);` to load up the xml into `$states_xml`.

Anyway to grab all `StateAbbr` and `StateName` from all `Table` elements in here to be outputted in an array, in one go??  Seems possible to me, but not sure how to approach this other than the way I'm currently doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate their parent element node. The expressions are relative to the node the SimpleXMLElement represents, but that is not needed in your case:

```
$diffgram = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$result = [];
foreach($diffgram->xpath('.//Table') as $table) {
  $result[] = [
    'Abbr' => trim($table->StateAbbr),
    'Name' => trim($table->StateName)
  ];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Abbr"]=>
    string(2) "AL"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(7) "Alabama"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Abbr"]=>
    string(2) "AK"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(6) "Alaska"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Abbr"]=>
    string(2) "AS"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(14) "American Samoa"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Abbr"]=>
    string(2) "AP"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(2) "AP"
  }
}
```

In DOM it looks nearly the same, but here you need Xpath expressions for the details.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$result = [];
foreach($xpath->evaluate('.//Table') as $table) {
  $result[] = [
    'Abbr' => $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(StateAbbr)', $table),
    'Name' => $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(StateName)', $table)  
  ];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this using [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/array_merge_recursive) :

```
$abbr = $states_xml->xpath('//StateAbbr');
$names = $states_xml->xpath('//StateName');
$tables = array_merge_recursive($abbr, $names);
```

display:

```
print_r($tables);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this single XPath,

```
//*[self::StateAbbr or self::StateName]
```

will return all `StateAbbr` and `StateName` elements in an XML document.

Comment: No, that doesn't work unfortunately.  I updated question with output of xml string.

Comment: Well, it does do what it's designed to do: select all `StateAbbr` and `StateName` elements with a single XPath.  If you actually want to retain the association between `StateAbbr` and `StateName` elements, then why don't you just select all tables?  E.g: `//Table`

Comment: Because `//Table` returns too much info and not able to parse it easily.  In any case, I decided to ditch the `xpath` approach and simply just do a `$states = json_decode(json_encode($states_xml), true);` than it's very simple after that, just need to call `$states['NewDataSet']['Table']` and it gives me what I need.  Thanks for your help all the same. :)

Comment: Sure thing.  I'm glad you found something that meets your needs.